# Issues in Cluster Environment on weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 (liferay DXP running)

Tags: weblogic12c, liferay-7

We have 2 node cluster in Weblogic running Liferay DXP. When we are trying to start the Node-2 we get the below error:

Any thoughts on this and what could be the best fix ? This is impacting our production and any help is appreciated.

> Jun 18, 2018 1:26:21 AM org.jgroups.protocols.UDP setBufferSize
>   WARNING: JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket MulticastSocket was
>   set to 500KB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB. This might lead to
>   performance problems. Please set your max receive buffer in the OS
>   correctly (e.g. net.core.rmem_max on Linux)  
>   1:26:21,354 AM EDT>

and we are getting in our logs:

> 01:26:21,484 ERROR [Start Level: Equinox Container:
>   123465678-1234-1234-1234-f0a48d1c8347][ClusterExecutorImpl:402] Unable
>   to get cluster node with address Servername-32883

Comment: Did you try "set[ting] your max receive buffer in the OS correctly" or searching this site?

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. we did increased "rmem_max"  to 500000 on prod and yet to give a try if this works or not.  Please let me know if this is not the setting your referring please. i will ask my Middleware engineers to check as well.

Comment: i did increased today on prod and that did not help. we are still getting the error mentioned below. 01:26:21,484 ERROR [Start Level: Equinox Container: 123465678-1234-1234-1234-f0a48d1c8347][ClusterExecutorImpl:402] Unable to get cluster node with address Servername-32883 ..................however we dont see that warning message we used to see earlier.

Comment: After increasing the OS level buffer , did  not solved the issue. However, we did UN-Linked the cluster on NODE-2, started the Node-2 and then NODE-2 was able to come up.....after that  - we did restarted the Node-1........and then, changed the settings of CLUSTER LINK ENABLED = true on Node-2  and restarted the node-2 - everything looks good....and what actual cause of the issue ?  - In review with Liferay and possible there is HOT FIX to come.